# How do I use @Published and map?

Tags: swift, combine

I want to use the `@Published` property wrapper combined with `map`, but I get this compiler error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Publishers.Map<Published.Publisher, Bool>' to return type 'Published.Publisher'

```
@Published private var aNumber: Int = 1

var theNumberIsZero2: Published<Bool>.Publisher {
   $aNumber.map { number -> Bool in
      return number == 0
   }
}
```

I could just use a `CurrentValueSubject`, like below, but I lost some benefit because `theNumberIsZero` cannot be synchronously checked.

```
private let currentValueNumber = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(0)
    
var theNumberIsZero: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
   currentValueNumber.map { number -> Bool in
      return number == 0
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it like this: by chaining value and isZero. Each time value updates isZero will update as well:

```
protocol ZeroChecking {

    var isZeroPublisher: Published<Bool>.Publisher { get }
}

class Number: ObservableObject, ZeroChecking {


    @Published var value: Int = 1
    @Published private(set) var isZero: Bool = false
    lazy var isZeroPublisher: Published<Bool>.Publisher = $isZero

    public init() {
        $value
            .map { $0 == 0 }
            .assign(to: &$isZero)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this approach won’t let me use this variable in a protocol though which is why I wanted to use the .publisher

Comment: I have updated my answer to include protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there with defining a computed property, which returns a publisher that maps values emitted by `@Published`, but it shouldn't be a `Published<Bool>.Publisher` type - it should just by an `AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>` type:

```
@Published private var aNumber: Int = 1

var theNumberIsZero2: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
   $aNumber.map { $0 == 0 }
           .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but want to point back to the piece of my question that talks about using the mapped property synchronously :(. I’d lose that benefit with this approach

Comment: @Dr.Mr.Uncle, what do you mean by using the mapped property synchronously? Can you add a code example to illustrate that use case?